# Tendency to discuss issues without subject matter competence

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying really hard to remember a word I learned recently which denotes one's tendency to discuss matters without subject matter competence, or fraudulently pretending to have it. Basically, to talk out of one's a.. I think the word starts with the letter U but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know of a word that fits this description?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ultracrepidarian - A person who expresses opinions on matters outside the scope of their knowledge or expertise.

OED includes it under US English:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ultracrepidarian

Comment: YESSSSSSS -- that's exactly the one !!  you sir (or madam) are not an ultracrepidarian when it comes to dictionary matters